# Calculadora hecha en python no pasa los tests

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este es el objetivo del proyecto (una calculadora inteligente hecha en python):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi código:

```
n = input()

def calculator(numbers):
    if ' ' in n:
        data = n.split()
        total = 0
        for i in data:
            total += int(i)
        print(total)
    elif n == '/help':
        print('The program calculates the sum of numbers')
    elif n == '/exit':
        print('Bye!')
    else:
        print(n)
    return None
calculator(n)
```

Por alguna razón no puedo pasar los tests, este es el error que obtengo:

```
Wrong answer in test #1

The program ended prematurely

Please find below the output of your program during this failed test.
Note that the '>' character indicates the beginning of the input line.

---

> /help
The program calculates the sum of numbers
```

Agradecería muchísimo su ayuda con esto, pues no puedo continuar con el proyecto...

Comment: Todo el contenido (o por lo menos el contenido que hace a la pregunta) debe estar en español...

Comment: Cual es el input que estas pasando cuando tenes un error?

Comment: Si se orienta el desarrollo a las pruebas, hay que saber cuál es el escenario de prueba que no estás pasando. Posiblemente el lío está en que sólo recibes el input una vez y, por el enunciado, parece que esperan que lo siga pidiendo hasta que pongas `/exit`

Answer (score 0):

El código tiene algunas inconsistencias. La función `calculador` recibe un parámetro que nunca usa. En su lugar, usas directamente una variable global, lo cual es mala idea.

También hay una forma corta de calcular la suma:

```
sum(float(x) for x in numbers.split())
```

`number.split()` divide el string `numbers` en una lista de strings, los que recorremos con `for`. Para cada elemento lo convertimos a float, generando una nueva lista. Finalmente, la función `sum` totaliza todos los valores.

También modifique la función para que retorne `False` cuando el usuario tipea `/exit` y `True` en otro caso. De esa manera se mantiene corriendo hasta que ingresas `/exit`.

Con todo, queda asi:

```
def calculator(numbers="/help"):
    if numbers == "/help":
        print('The program calculates the sum of numbers')
    elif numbers == "/exit":
        print('Bye!')
        return False;
    else:
        print(sum(float(x) for x in numbers.split()))

    return True

n = "/help"
while calculator(n):
    n = input(">")
```

produce

```
The program calculates the sum of numbers
>1 2 3
6.0
>/exit
Bye!

Process finished with exit code 0
```